# How can I exit a starmap_async process running in an multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, exit, terminate, starmap

I am having a lot of data (more than one million) and need to do some calculation on it that finds a certain value out of the millions. This is time consuming. To speed up the process I am trying to use all cores of the CPU. To do this, I am using multiprocessing-pool and I am calling the worker process with starmap_async (I need to hand over multiple arguments). Basically, it works so far with the limitation that I have to wait until all values of the list are executed and all processes are finished before I can continue. Is there a possibility to end the starmap process once one of the processes finds a correct value?

I have already tried several different things such as terminating from the worker process changing the whole structure to a for loop but it seems that the starmap process needs to run to its end and that they cannot be stopped. The only way seems to extract each list-value individually and feed it to a separate Process which creates again a big overhead and slows down the process significantly. 
Does anyone have an idea?

The solution described here [Terminate a Python multiprocessing program once a one of its workers meets a certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962462/terminate-a-python-multiprocessing-program-once-a-one-of-its-workers-meets-a-cer) looks the same but it is not. I have tried this but it doesn’t work. The difference seems to be that none of the arguments is the iterable in the described issue. I have played with this and I couldn’t  get it to end the processes before the starmap process finished completely. In the recommended solution the processes are started and ran independently until one finds a solution. In my case starmap seems to continue feeding the processes without checking termination conditions.

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(x, arg1, arg2):
    some calculation with all arguments
    **#here I need a possibility to cancel all processes and return the current x value**

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg1 = somthing
    arg2 = somthing_else
    value_list = (a,b,c,d,e,.......)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_count()) 
    p = pool.starmap_async(worker, [(value_list, arg1, arg2) for x in value_list])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    for y in p:
        if y = correct_value:
            print(correct_value)
            break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminate a Python multiprocessing program once a one of its workers meets a certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962462/terminate-a-python-multiprocessing-program-once-a-one-of-its-workers-meets-a-cer)

Comment: Youl'd have to set up some type of signaling between the main process and the workers. If the worker had knowledge of what it was looking for it could signal the main process when /if it found it. The workers would have to periodically check to see if they could stop.