# python parallel processing and select best code

Tags: python, parallel-processing

i have code like this .

```
import multiprocessing 
import time 

class Process(multiprocessing.Process): 
    def __init__(self, id): 
        super(Process, self).__init__() 
        self.id = id
                 
    def run(self): 
        time.sleep(1) 

        print("run "+"."+str(self.id))
```

can i build   n process that  run same time and when one of them finish stopping all other processes?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of ways. basically, you need some of sync. once the condition reached, the rest of the processes calls terminate function

for details, see this:

[Terminate a Python multiprocessing program once a one of its workers meets a certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962462/terminate-a-python-multiprocessing-program-once-a-one-of-its-workers-meets-a-cer)